# Do i need a ssl-certificate for my debian server to communicate with the APNS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I'm currently learning to develop for iOS and reached the points where i want to play around with some push-notifications. 
I was able to use the developing certificate to register the iPhone for Push-Notifications but now i want to establish a connection between my debian rootserver and the APNS (for the first try i'll connect to the sandbox-server). 
Some tutorials showed me how to receive a certificate for my Mac but therefore I need a valid certificate for my server or am I wrong with this assumption?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the APNS works with apple certificates only. In short:

- Create an app id in provisioning portal
- Enable it for push notifications
- Generate certificates following the usual procedure.
- Combine the generated certificate and private key into one .pem and us it in communicating with apple.

This tutorial was all I needed:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/

Comment: yes this is the tutorial i worked with but he is using his Mac to send push-notifications to the APNS.. i wanted to know if i need a extra certificate when i want to send it from my Root-Server.

Comment: You only need the Apple certificate. No SSL- or other certificate is needed. By exporting and appending the private key as the tutorial suggests, the certificate becomes usable from outside the Mac.

Comment: ok, when i do this i've got the message: "No client certificate CA names sent" and " Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)" do you know how this happened?

Comment: The tutorial shows a command you can use to test the certificate: openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 
    -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem ... Does this work?

Comment: this is the command I tested with and got the error from above.

Comment: i suppose openssl might need some sort of certificate system (with certificate authorities) to work properly... unfortunately this is outside of my comfort zone. I hope someone else can pitch in.

Comment: i've solved it by myself. I tried it directly with the php script which sends a notification and it worked! Thanks for your help!